# How can solving for $u$ to obtain the inverse function be completed here?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, probability-distributions, exponential-function, inverse-function

The text I'm working in has this cdf function

$$F(x)=1-\left(1+5 e^{-x}\right)^{-.2}, \quad-\infty<x<\infty$$

For the inverse of the cdf, it then sets $u=F(x)$ and solves for $u$. After that it provides this for the inverse cdf without showing any steps.

$$F^{-1}(u)=\log \left\{.2\left[(1-u)^{-5}-1\right]\right\}, \quad 0<u<1$$

I am trying to work through and solve this on my own and I am getting stuck at what should be the last step. I'm coming up with the inverse function they provide, but it's equal to $-x$, not $x$. Is there some obvious way to get to just $x$ from where I'm leaving off, or am I making some error working my way to it?

\begin{align}
u &= 1-\left(1+5 e^{-x}\right)^{-.2} \\
1-u &= \left(1+5 e^{-x}\right)^{-.2} \\
(1-u)^{-5} &= 1+5 e^{-x} \\
(1-u)^{-5} - 1 &= 5 e^{-x} \\
.2[(1-u)^{-5} - 1] &= e^{-x} \\
\log \left\{.2\left[(1-u)^{-5}-1\right]\right\}&=-x \\
\end{align}

At this point $F^{-1}(u)$ should equal $x$, but I'm stuck with $-x$. Thank you for any assistance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your derivation is correct. There is a typo in the question statement. It should be $5e^x$ and not $5e^{-x}$. Namely,  in the last line of your attempt, there's indeed no negative sign for the lone $x$ on the right hand side.

For a plot, see [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Plot%5B1+-+%281+%2B+5+Exp%5Bx%5D%29%5E%28-1%2F5%29%2C+%7Bx%2C+-10%2C+10%7D%5D&wal=header). You can see what happens when you try to change the correct `5Exp[x]` to the WRONG `5Exp[-x]`.

Basically, you can check that $F(x) \to 0$ when $x \to -\infty$ and $F(x) \to 1$ when $x \to \infty$.
Here to make this even clearer, the correct CDF is
$$F(x) = 1-\frac1{(1+5 e^{x})^{1/5}}$$
as $x \to \infty$ the denominator blows up and makes the whole fraction vanish, resulting in the leading $1$ (probability one) as needed.

Comment: Thank you for your help!